# C/C++ va_arg - Is there a way to skip an argument?

Tags: c++, c, variadic-functions

I am wanting to add functionality to sprintf(). Specifically, I want to be able to pass my own POD data types to it, but I am unsure of how to do this.

Supposedly, if you create the va_list, you can pass it off to vsprintf() and have it do the hard work for you - but I still need to access the va_list, and extract items myself before passing the va_list to vsprintf().

For example, assume the following code:

```
struct mypod {
    int somedata;
}; // just for example, you know

// somewhere else in the code...
mypod mp;
mp.somedata = 5325;
my_sprintf(myChrPtr, "%z", mp);
```

With the new %z code corresponding to my new data type.

I understand only pointers and POD structures can be passed, that's no big deal. I am wondering, though, that what happens if I get to the end of the va_list (by getting the args using va_arg()) and then pass it to vsprintf()?

Thank you!

Comment: Personally, when faced with a similar challenge, rather than writing a wrapper around `*printf`, I just create a routine to output a string from the struct/object, and then print the resulting string the way you would any other string.  I think the code resulting code is a lot easier to follow.

Comment: Note that the lower-case letters are served for the standards bodies; upper-case letters are allowed for format extensions (but it might not be wise even so).  In particular, `z` is a modifier (indicating a `size_t` value) in C99.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that `va_arg` must be called in the right order and with the right type for proper behavior I think you have to consume the `fmt` piecemeal while processing the parts you care about and passing the rest to `vsprintf`:

```
void
mysprintf(char *dst, char *fmt, ...)
{
    char *p = fmt;
    va_list va;

    va_start(va, fmt);
    do {
        char *q = strchr(p, '|');
        if (q) {
            /* really should take const char *fmt and not write on it like this... */
            *q++ = '\0';
        }
        dst += vsprintf(dst, p, va);  /* let vsprintf do a subset */
        if (q) {
            dst += sprintf(dst, "%d", va_arg(va, int));  /* consume 1 int */
        }
        p = q;
    } while (p);

    va_end(va);
}


strcpy(fmt, "%s|%s|%s");  /* mutable fmt */
mysprintf(buf, fmt, "hello", 7, "world", 8, "!");
```

In my example I just took `|` to be like `%d` but a real example with additional `%...` escapes will be much more complex.

Comment: This is a good way to do it but it would probably be a pretty big project to make a function equivalent to printf with all its specifiers.

Comment: @Seth: You misunderstand:  You don't re-implement `vsprintf`, that's what the call in the middle is for.  The more complex part is handing something more than `|`->`int`, since the question was for `%z`->`class` which is more work than `strchr`

Comment: @Ben Jackson: So, what you're saying is use a format specifier other than what sprintf uses? That still wouldn't work really well, as I still have to remove all instances of my own data type from the va_list before sending it to vsprintf. See my comment on Seth's answer.

Comment: @FurryHead:  Your view of the solution is "preprocess fmt and va_list doing my part and then calling vsprintf".  I don't think you can do that, but you can do what I described:  Let vsprintf do everything up to your first class argument, process that, repeat.

Comment: @Ben Jackson: Aaaah, I see. I will try to implement that, and will get back with you with how well it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Ben Jackson: Well, what an idiot I am. I modified/adapted your code without testing it first, having forgotten many of the code examples given on here are mentally compiled rather than computer compiled. I tried, tried, tried, and could not get it to work - then, only then, tried your unmodified code: It doesn't work. It gives a segfault if you try to read and/or modify p... I haven't yet figured out why.

Comment: @FurryHead:  It does work.   Do you see in the example where I explicitly call out `/* mutable fmt */` and in the body that writing on `fmt` is problematic?  You probably tried it with a (read-only) string constant which then crashes when the code temporarily nul-terminates it to do the partial `vsprintf`.

Comment: This answer is not valid in standard C.  After the `vsprintf()` call, the value of `va` is indeterminate, and must be passed to the `va_end()` macro before any further use of it.

Comment: @Ben Jackson: Oooops, I totally missed that. Yeah, I did call it with a string constant, like I do with scanf, printf, all the other format functions. My bad. @caf: Does that still apply to C++? I am not using this from C, but rather from C++.

Comment: @FurryHead: The C++ standard doesn't appear to alter the restrictions placed on `va_arg()`, so the same would still apply there too.

Answer (score 1):

Make two `va_list`s and use only one to do what you need to do, then pass the other one to `vsprintf` or whatever:

```
va_list l1 = va_start(final_arg);
va_list l2 = va_start(final_arg);

// do stuff with l1 and l2 will be unaffected

vsprintf(/*using l2*/);
```

Remember that a va_list is really only a pointer to a place on the stack (it's implementation-specific I guess, but that's how it is where I come from). `va_arg` returns the thing pointed to by the `va_list` casted to the specified type, and increments the pointer by `sizeof(thetype)`. So if you get two pointers and keep one without modifying it, you can just pass that to another function.

I hope I didn't misunderstand the question.

Comment: First, it's vsprintf I want to use. ;)    Second, it would make sense to remove the custom % codes before passing it to vsprintf() - Third, I still don't know how to skip over an argument. Thanks, though!

Comment: `vsprintf` would be the same. And to skip over an argument would be a little more difficult, if it were me I would use a bytebuffer class, adding to the buffer all the arguments I didn't want to skip, and pass the pointer to the top of it as the `va_list` vsprintf would be expecting. But I think you'd want a simpler way, and I don't know it. Sorry.

Comment: @FurryHead Unless you wanted to modify the stack directly (copy everything after the item you want to remove over it, similar to removing an item from the middle of an array), which would be living on the edge :)

Comment: Haha, I suppose not. I intend to use %z for my own items, but what I meant was to remove from the va_list my own data types otherwise something like `my_sprintf(chrPtr, "Testing my %s at %z in the %s region", chrPtr, myData, chrPtr);` - if that va_list is passed to vsprintf(), it will see the second %s pointing to myData which is not good!

Comment: @FurryHead Yeah, that's what I mean. You'd copy chrPtr over myData and just remove the %z.